# Nginx as virtual host and as reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I have GlassFish (a java application server) running on an Ubuntu server. I have also phppgadmin running on a different port, let say 5555 and configured with apache.

I use Nginx as a Reverse Proxy in front of GlassFish. (Ssl and configs for port 443 hasn't been set yet.)

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     my_domain;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://my_ip_number:8080;
  }
  
  location /phppgadmin {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  
        proxy_pass http://my_ip_number:5555/phppgadmin;
  }  
}
```

When I try to create a virtual host for PostfixAdmin like described [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfixadmin-create-virtual-mailboxes-ubuntu-20-04) by setting following file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. In `http://postfixadmin.my_domain/setup.php` I  see only a 404 page from glassfish.
A DNS `A` record for the subdomain is set.
What is wrong with my config? How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name postfixadmin.my_domain;

   root /usr/share/postfixadmin/public/;
   index index.php index.html;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/postfixadmin_access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/postfixadmin_error.log;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ ^/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized the way my server is set-up, it is not possible to achieve what I was trying to do above. Creating a virtual host for PostfixAdmin is not necessary!

Here is my final configuration and everything works fine.

```
server {
  listen          my_ip_number:80;
  server_name     example.com www.example.com;

  include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log; # upstreamlog;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";

        proxy_pass http://my_ip_number:8080;
  }

  location /phppgadmin {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://my_ip_number:5555/phppgadmin;
  }


  location /mypostfixadmin {
        proxy_pass http://my_ip_number:5555/postfixadmin;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 0;
  }

}
```